# Using Pandas finding close vectors in large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, distance, similarity

For a similarity project I need to analyse 1000-dimensional feature-vectors and find closest (I've got certain empirical threshold using [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry), i.e. [scipy.spatial.distance.cityblock](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cityblock.html)). I have couple million vectors to compare initially and there will be more constantly adding.

I'm thinking of using Pandas to solve the task. Would it work? Should I split my data set into several segments?

Vectors consist of positive real numbers (mostly up to 10) and zeros.

```
    ...
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.00627385638654232,
    0.0,
    9.711357051855884e-07,
    0.0,
    2.1105501651763916,
    0.0,
    2.3891907896533837e-10,
    0.0,
    0.16674332320690155,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    4.790003475844827e-27,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    3.0351770901292097e-13,
    0.06621165573596954,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    1.1311118331775704e-17,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    7.631283341843815e-20,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    1.6503195254813363e-08,
    2.1143353508292794e-26,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.7260096073150635,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.6851852536201477,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.005956938490271568,
    ...
```

Comment: This question is not really answerable as written.  I suggest you try to implement a solution then let us know if you have more specific questions.

Comment: Looks a good question, but lacking detail, so hard to give answer: (1) please provide some samples of your data: `1000-dimensional feature vectors` - what are they? vector of 1000 what? numbers? labels? strings? (2) what is Manhattan distance? how is it comuted (3) is your data _couple million_ * 1000? (4) provide min working example an answer can be built upon https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. It is really a lot of work before is becomes a good answereable question.